# When we take input in a string why size does not matter?

Tags: c, string, scanf, gets, puts

```
#include<stdio.h>`

int main() {
  char b[1];
  scanf("%s",b);
  puts(b);
  // gets(b);
  // puts(b);
  // gets(b);
  // puts(b);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
hello_world
hello_world
```

I expect that it should give max limit error but it didn't gave that. Why?

Comment: If you want to impose a limit, you must do so.  eg `char b[10]; if( scanf("%9s", b) == 1 ) ...`.  Failure to impose a limit often leads to undefined behavior.  Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including the behavior you would expect if you didn't overflow the buffer.

Comment: "max limit error" is not a mandated behaviour for **Undefined Behaviour**. **UB** can manifest itself with "program behaves as if it was coded safely (except when the boss/teacher is watching)"

Comment: The `gets` function is unsafe and has been removed from the language. Never use it.

Comment: Scanf is actually writing into undefined memory since it doesn't check the buffer length.

Comment: regarding: `char b[1];
  scanf("%s",b);`   the `%s` format specifier always appending a NUL byte to the input  ( result: a buffer of 1 will always be overflowed, resulting in undefined behavior )

Answer (score 2):

"give max limit error" --> C does not specify a "max limit error" required.

C is like riding a bicycle without training wheels.  If code is not well directed, it fails.

Use a larger buffer and a width limit like:

```
char b[100];
scanf("%99s",b);
```

Answer (score 0):

`char b[1];` says to reserve one byte of memory for `b`.

`scanf("%s",b);` says to read any number of characters (until a white-space character is seen) and put them in memory starting at `b`.

So this code asks to write to memory that is not reserved for `b`. Nothing in the C language stops you from doing that. You are **allowed** by the C language to ask to do “improper” things; it is deliberately a language for having low-level control of various parts of the computer. The C standard does not specify what happens when you do that; it is up to you, and other tools, to take care with what you are doing when you go beyond what the standard defines.

If writing to that memory happens not to break anything else your program needs to continue “working,” then the program might “work.” If it does break something else, the program can fail in various ways. Also note that the C standard permits the compiler to optimize your program in ways that will not affect programs that are fully defined by the C standard but that may cause surprising effects in programs that are not fully defined by the standard.